# inexplicable for-comprehension result in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, for-comprehension, partialfunction

I understand for-expression is translated into map and flatMap. But I found something that I can not explain and need your helps. Here are two toy examples:

```
for {
    None <- List(Option(1),None)
} yield 0

//res0: List[Int] = List(0, 0)
```

**Q1:** Why Some(1) is map to 0 ? I was expecting List(0),

**update1:**
thanks the comment of @marios , ths one is more bizarre.
`for(None <- List(Some(1), None) ) yield None` returns `List(Some(1), None)`.

**update2:**
some says it is a variable, but in IDE, it really links to a `None` object.

---

I use IntelliJ to auto-translate the above for-expression to map-expression:

```
List(Option(1), None).map { case None => 0 }  

//scala.MatchError: Some(1)
```

**Q2:** The error from this map-expression is expected, while the for-expression in first question doesn't give me this error. Why they get the different computation ?

Comment: for(None <- List(Some(1), None) ) yield None. This returns List(Some(1), None). This is so bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Scala compiler. The [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) states: "In a first step, every generator `p <- e`, where `p` is not irrefutable for the type of `e` is replaced by `p <- e.withFilter { case p => true; case _ => false }`", and then "a for comprehension for `(p <- e) yield e′` is translated to `e.map { case p => e′ }`."

This means your example, `for { None <- List(Option(1), None) } yield 0`, should be translated to

```
List(Option(1),None).withFilter { case None => true; case _ => false }.map{case None => 0}
```

which evaluates to `List(0)`, as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

These two return the same result.

```
for(None <- List(Some(1), None) ) yield None
for(x <- List(Some(1), None) ) yield x
```

It appears that `None <-` is not an effective means to throw away a value.  Instead it just creates a temporary variable that masks the `None` object.

Comment: i was thinking same re: masking issue. I've never seen for comprehension used the way the asker is using it.... pretty bizarre, or is that somewhat common?

Comment: No, it's not variable. In IDE (IntelliJ worksheet), it really links to `None` object of `Option` type. It is a pattern matching.